# how to add line break whitin popup data-tooltip in Semantic-UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, tooltip, semantic-ui

I'd like make total 3 sentence, using add line break inside data-tooltip
I've been tried but it wasn't working

```
    <div class="ui icon button" data-html="true"
    data-tooltip="The default theme's basic popup <br/> 
removes the pointing arrow." 
    data-position="bottom center">
      <i class="add icon"></i>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this:

```
<div class="ui icon button" data-html="<div class='content'>The default theme's basic 
popup <br/> removes the pointing arrow.</div></div>" data-position="bottom center">
   <i class="add icon"></i>
</div>
```

or this one, in this format you can use every html tag you need:

```
<div class="ui icon button test">
    <i class="add icon"></i>
</div>
<div class="ui custom popup top left transition hidden">
    The default theme's basic popup 
    <br/>
    removes the pointing arrow.
</div>
```

and use this script:

```
<script>
    $(".test.button").popup({
       popup : $(".custom.popup"),
       on    : 'hover'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, but i can't fixed it. my script isn't working.

Comment: your script should run after your DOM is ready. So you write like this:
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".test.button").popup({
       popup : $(".custom.popup"),
       on    : 'hover'
    });
});